# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Did Vin MoCap the Dance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/did-vin-mocap-the-dance)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Did Bill's bullet cause any brain damage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/did-bills-bullet-cause-any-brain-damage)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What happened to Mike and Carol's former spouses?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23530/what-happened-to-mike-and-carols-former-spouses)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Rusty Nail's location?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24116/rusty-nails-location)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why does King Schultz go to such distance in order to help Django?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23723/why-does-king-schultz-go-to-such-distance-in-order-to-help-django)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Attack on a person resting in a parked car](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23469/attack-on-a-person-resting-in-a-parked-car)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 18, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In which show was someone named "Moo Goo Gai Pan"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23873/in-which-show-was-someone-named-moo-goo-gai-pan)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Which place was Samantha talking about at the end of HER?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23434/which-place-was-samantha-talking-about-at-the-end-of-her)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 20, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [woman answers door wearing saran wrap](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23509/woman-answers-door-wearing-saran-wrap)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Films released in additional version without the score?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23641/films-released-in-additional-version-without-the-score)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 11)

---

Comment: I was going to complain about an unfair distribution, but while 22% of all questions asked are identify-this-movie tagged, 20% of the eval questions were, so I guess it was fair. I do find it remarkable, however, that even though one of the ident questions in the eval is one of the best written question of that type I've seen here, it still only garnered a 4. The other one got a -4. Grrr.

Comment: @CGCampbell Whoa, we're at 22% now? Wasn't this always some 18-20%? Screams for a cleanup, I guess.

Comment: identify-this-movie: 1305, -tv-show: 235, -actor: 39, -episode: 14; some -tv-show's are also -movies, all of the -episode's are also -movies and/or -tv-shows, so they dont' add anything useful; total questions: 5872; 1305/5872=22.2% plus a few -tv-show that aren't also tagged -movie; I would guess 25% of all questions are identify-this-. I have resolved to stop bugging about it, because that is who we are, for better or worse.